# ExtJs + Angular модальное окно

Tags: bootstrap, angularjs, extjs

Есть приложение на extJs4. В нем есть вкладки (tab). На одной из вкладок iframe со страницей на angularJs . На странице с angular есть кнопка по которой вызывается модальное окно $modal (ui.bootstrap). И при его открытии пропадают табы. Т.е. у div который отвечает за вкладку свойство top перестает действовать. Хотя через консоль хрома оно есть и если через консоль его переустановить (убрать и поставить снова), то вкладки появляются. 
Куда копать?
Спасибо.
p.s. все стили стандартные.